# typedef did not replaced with the datatype

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, typedef

I was surprised with the following piece of code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef int type;

int main( )
{
    type type = 10;
    printf( "%d", type );
}
```

This went through and output of the program is 10.

But when I changed the code slightly as below,

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef int type;

int main()
{
    type type = 10;
    float f = 10.9898;
    int x;
    x = (type) f;
    printf( "%d, %d", type, x);
}
```

in aCC compiler:

> "'type' is used as a type, but has not been defined as a type."

in g++ compiler:

> "error: expected `;' before f"

Is it that the compiler did not recognize the pattern in the second case, as this pattern can be related to assignment of a variable, evaluation of an expression etc and in the first case as this pattern is only used while defining a variable compiler recognized it.

Comment: please remove line numbers.

Comment: Hint: all you need is one ::

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`typedef` identifiers, like variable names, also has a scope. After

```
type type = 10;
```

the variable `type` shadows the type name `type`. For instance, this code

```
typedef int type;
int main( )
{
    type type = 10;
    type n;   //compile error, type is not a type name
}
```

won't compile for the same reason, in C++, you can use `::type` to refer to the type name:

```
typedef int type;
int main( )
{
    type type = 10;
    ::type n;  //compile fine
}
```

Comment: +1 and to get the global `type` defined, you've to use `::type` which chis mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @legends2k In C++, yes, I'll add an example to illustrate that.

Comment: @legends2k Correct, but this doesn's anwer the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I thought the explanation on shadowing does answer the question, no?

Comment: @legends2k I think the question is why doesn't the language figure out that `type` is a type from the context.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The question from the OP doesn't seem to be one of rationale of the standard. Atleast, it isn't as explicitly worded as you do.